# Smaller font-size if the string length of the div is greater than 10

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string-length

I have a div that I want to detect the length of; if it's 10 or more, I want it to display in a smaller font-size.

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  function adjustFontSize() {
    var theTitleLength = $('.article-title-on-list').text.length;
    if (theTitleLength >= 10) {
      $('.article-title-on-list').css('font-size', '1.5rem');
    } else {
      $('.article-title-on-list').css('font-size', '2rem');
    };
  };
  adjustFontSize();
};
```

```html
<div class="article-title-on-list">12345678901234567890</div>
```

The function fails silently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`text` is method and not property. use `.text()` instead of `.text`

```
 var theTitleLength = $('.article-title-on-list').text().length;
```

Answer (score 0):

I've updated my code with an .each() function. In case someone want to use this:

```js
$('.article-title-on-list').each(function() {
  var theTitleLength = $(this).text().length;
  console.log(theTitleLength);
  if (theTitleLength >= 14) {
    $(this).css('font-size', '1.7rem');
  } else {
    $(this).css('font-size', '2rem');
  };
});
```

```html
<div class="article-title-on-list">12345678901234567890</div>
<div class="article-title-on-list">123456789012345678901234567890</div>
<div class="article-title-on-list">1234567890</div>
```

Thanks again for Nathan's help.